# HealthKit is launching only once in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, healthkit

I have integrated HealthKit framework into my application. The HealthKit is launching only once from the application.The below Code is in the singleton class created for HealthKit.

```
func requestAuthorization()
        {

            if (HKHealthStore .isHealthDataAvailable() == false)
            {
                return
            }


            let healthKitTypesToRead : Set = [
                HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierFitzpatrickSkinType)!,
                HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex)!,
                HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType)!
            ]

            let healthKitTypesToWrite : Set = [
                HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyFatPercentage)!,
                HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex)!,
                HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)!,
                HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass)!,
                HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierLeanBodyMass)!
            ]


                self.healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) {
                    (success, error) -> Void in
                    if !success{
                        print("error")
                    }
                }
            }
```

The method `requestAuthorization` is calling for button action from the viewcontroller,

```
@IBAction func healthIntegrationButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        HealthKitHandler.shared.requestAuthorization()

    }
```

Once I dismiss the healthkit app, then no action is happening for the button action. Again if I deleted the application from simulator & click the button healthkit app will launch.

Could anyone please help us what is wrong in the above code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the authorization has been already granted, the app won't show it again. It will just call the success handler directly.

Change your `completion` handler into:

```
self.healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) {
                (success, error) -> Void in
                if success {
                    print("success!")
                }
                else {
                    print("error")
                }
            }
```

and you should see the difference.

Comment: so if suppose i want to launch the app again how should i proceed

Comment: @suji You are not doing anything wrong. Always call the authorization code but don't expect it to show authorization dialog to the user.